# Can you use solr_query in Cassandra to find map field containing some particular value?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, solr-query-syntax

I would like to use solr_query to find results which field of map type contains given key-value pair.

I'm trying to create a query similar to this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE pathId= 5 AND solr_query='validity: [1970-01-01T00:01:00 TO *] ’ AND metadata[1] = '2' LIMIT 1 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table where metadata['1'] = '2' AND solr_query=$${ "q": "pathid:5", "fq": "validity:[1970-01-01T00:01:00 TO *]";
```

however each time I'm getting `ServerError: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Search queries must have only one index expression.` error.

I would like to be able to somehow query with those 3 conditions in 'where' clause - `pathid` `validity` and `metadata`.
Is it possible to query for map containing given key-value pair inside `solr_query`, or is there any other way to do that?

I have created a search index on fields:

```sql
create SEARCH index on my_table with columns validity, pathId, metadata;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra Map fields are handled in DSE Search as dynamic fields. In order to work with these it is important that the Map keys follow the pattern `<fieldname>_<key>`. So, in your case, you would have to insert keys with the form `metadata_key1`, `metadata_key2` ...

If you follow that naming convention, you can then query the data as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where solr_query=$${ "q": "pathid:5 AND metadata_key1:2", "fq": "validity:[1970-01-01T00:01:00 TO *]";
```

Use of dynamic fields in DSE Search is documented [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/usingDynamicFields.html).